# AngularJS: How to pass socket.io service data to corresponding directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, socket.io

Using a socketio service I would like to pass new data to directives.
Passing the actual data already works and I receive new values within the directive. For this purpose I call the socketio service from within the directive and pass a callback to the service as a parameter.

**Goal**

Receive device information (device name, device state) via socket.io service and update the corresponding scope (`$scope.value.device_state`) of the corresponding device directive.

**Issue**

There are multiple instances of the directive. Everytime the directive is instanciated, a new callback function is sent to the socketio service and gets registered. This way multiple callbacks are executed if new data is received by the socketio service.

**Issue Example**

The directive is instantiated 7 times. If new data is received by the socket.io service, it seems like every of the 7 directives gets notified 7 times that new data is available.

**Controller**

The controller loads an initial JSON containing information about multiple devices. The devices are referenced by the name (device_name).

```
[{"device_name":"device1","device_state":"ON"},{"device_name":"device2","device_state":"OFF"}]
```

**View**

The view displays the device state of every device.

```
<div>{{value.device_state}}</div>
```

**Socket.io Service**

The socket.io service receives new device states and runs the callback.

```
app.service('service_websocket', function () {
    var api = {};
    var socket = io.connect();

    api.getDeviceState = function(callback) {
        socket.on('send:device_state', callback);
    };

    return api;
});
```

**Socket.io Service Data Received**

This is how the new data looks like. It means "device2" should be set "ON".

```
{"device_name":"device2","device_state":"ON"}
```

**Directive**

The directive passes the callback to the socket.io service. It is the same callback for every directive. As soon as new data is received it should update the device_state of the corresponding device (referenced by device_name).

```
.directive('device', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            value: '='
        },
        templateUrl: 'templates/partial_device.tpl.html',
        controller: ['$scope', 'service_device', 'service_websocket',function($scope, service_device, service_websocket) {
            service_websocket.getDeviceState(function(data) {
                if($scope.value.device_name == data.device_name) {
                    $scope.value.device_state = data.device_state;
                }
            });
        }]
    };
});
```

**Question**

How would you implement this?
Any help is more than appreciated.

Comment: Instead of relying on binding and calling directly to the socket io service get device state, what you want is to put a mediator between those two. In the service_websocket you can use some kind of listener pattern. The first cal to getDeviceState do the actual socket.on registration and then keep the callback in a list. Other calls to getDeviceState just register themselves in that list. The callback to socket.on should implement logic that calls each of those listeners.

Comment: Thank you very much. Multiple socket.on registrations caused the issue that the callbacks were called multiple times.The first call to getDeviceState now does the actual socket.on registration. Other calls to getDeviceState just register themselves in a list.

Answer (score 0):

> Issue
>
> There are multiple instances of the directive. Everytime the directive
>   is instanciated, a new callback function is sent to the socketio
>   service and gets registered. This way multiple callbacks are executed
>   if new data is received by the socketio service.

well your event `send:device_state` doesn't encapsulate any meaningful "state".
if you have multiple device (directives) in your page registered to that event all of them would obviously be triggered.

1) You can consider refactoring your server side code and send for example a custom event like `send:device_state_device2` that target a specific device (you have already this information in the json)

2) Or you can handle this client side keeping a map of callback and decide which one to trigger

```
var cb = {}; //map of callback
function wrapperFn(){
 return function(data){
    //trigger the callback only of the target device if exists
    cb[data.device_name] && cb[data.device_name](); 
 }
}
api.getDeviceState = function(deviceName, callback) {
  cb[deviceName] = callback || function(){};
  socket.on('send:device_state', wrapperFn());
};
```

Another thing to note is that the callback you're passing to the service is executed outside angular environment, in order to reflect the changes to your template you should manually trigger a dygest cycle wrapping your code in an `$apply`

```
service_websocket.getDeviceState(function(data) {
   $scope.$apply(function(){
     if($scope.value.device_name == data.device_name) {
        $scope.value.device_state = data.device_state;
     }
   });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Your wrapper function and dygest cycle combined with @Brian Tompsett - 汤莱恩 suggestions solved the issue.